# How to add a single-pixel outline post-processing shader to Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

I've not found a single resource on this matter. I've found a few online examples, but none is conclusive.

[outliner http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/02o.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/02o.png)

I've [implemented and uploaded](http://viclib.com/helvite/guloid/) the effect I want using WebGL. The question is, how do I incorporate it on Three.js?

Comment: The linked page is blank.

Comment: @Wold you must wait some time, it is loading huge animation files. Follow the network tab on your browser console. The shader itself can also be seen there.

Comment: Can you show your three.js example? What are the online examples you have found? How are they not adequate. What are your requirements?

Comment: @WestLangley I don't have a Three.js example. My requirement is that the lines must be one pixel wide and must use normals and depth information with adjustable parameters so it won't miss any outline. In other words, it would be easier if I could just set my own post-processing shader, which is what I want.

Comment: See this example from three.js r.66: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing2.html You are free to implement your own postprocessing shader in three.js.